# R function to copy data from one column to another under a third condition

Tags: r, tidyr

I try to copy the long/lat values (long || lat), in the column long_origin lat_origin (currently empty), based on the value and I can't find the ad hoc function
any help would be appreciated

Data

```
head(origin5,n = 15)
      Numéro Kanton     long      lat Kanton_origin long_origin lat_origin
1  PGV02.064     FR 571183.5 174640.0            VD                       
2  PGV02.064     NE 548363.0 206421.0            VD                       
3  PGV02.064     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD                       
4  PGV02.064     VS 614169.5 122992.5            VD                       
5  PGV02.026     GE 499192.0 122622.5            VD                       
6  PGV01.079     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD                       
7  PGV02.003     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD                       
8  PGV01.108     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD                       
9  PGV02.036     BE 616990.0 187209.0            FR                       
10 PGV03.026     FR 571183.5 174640.0            FR                       
11 PGV02.036     TI 702684.0 120482.0            FR                       
12 PGV02.036     VD 539884.5 159601.0            FR                       
13 PGV03.034     BE 616990.0 187209.0            NE                       
14 PGV03.034     GE 499192.0 122622.5            NE                       
15 PGV03.034     NE 548363.0 206421.0            NE
```

**expected result:**

```
      Numéro Kanton     long      lat Kanton_origin long_origin lat_origin
1  PGV02.064     FR 571183.5 174640.0            VD    539884.5  159601.0                    
2  PGV02.064     NE 548363.0 206421.0            VD    539884.5 159601.0                   
3  PGV02.064     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD    539884.5 159601.0                  
4  PGV02.064     VS 614169.5 122992.5            VD    539884.5 159601.0                 
5  PGV02.026     GE 499192.0 122622.5            VD    539884.5 159601.0                   
6  PGV01.079     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD    539884.5 159601.0                   
7  PGV02.003     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD    539884.5 159601.0                   
8  PGV01.108     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD    539884.5 159601.0                   
9  PGV02.036     BE 616990.0 187209.0            FR    571183.5 174640.0                   
10 PGV03.026     FR 571183.5 174640.0            FR    571183.5 174640.0                   
11 PGV02.036     TI 702684.0 120482.0            FR    571183.5 174640.0                   
12 PGV02.036     VD 539884.5 159601.0            FR    571183.5 174640.0                   
13 PGV03.034     BE 616990.0 187209.0            NE    548363.0 206421.0                    
14 PGV03.034     GE 499192.0 122622.5            NE    548363.0 206421.0                    
15 PGV03.034     NE 548363.0 206421.0            NE    548363.0 206421.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result via `dplyr::distinct` and `dplyr::left_join` like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

origin5 %>% 
  left_join(distinct(origin5, Kanton, long, lat), by = c("Kanton_origin" = "Kanton"), suffix = c("", "_origin"))
#>       Numéro Kanton     long      lat Kanton_origin long_origin lat_origin
#> 1  PGV02.064     FR 571183.5 174640.0            VD    539884.5     159601
#> 2  PGV02.064     NE 548363.0 206421.0            VD    539884.5     159601
#> 3  PGV02.064     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD    539884.5     159601
#> 4  PGV02.064     VS 614169.5 122992.5            VD    539884.5     159601
#> 5  PGV02.026     GE 499192.0 122622.5            VD    539884.5     159601
#> 6  PGV01.079     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD    539884.5     159601
#> 7  PGV02.003     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD    539884.5     159601
#> 8  PGV01.108     VD 539884.5 159601.0            VD    539884.5     159601
#> 9  PGV02.036     BE 616990.0 187209.0            FR    571183.5     174640
#> 10 PGV03.026     FR 571183.5 174640.0            FR    571183.5     174640
#> 11 PGV02.036     TI 702684.0 120482.0            FR    571183.5     174640
#> 12 PGV02.036     VD 539884.5 159601.0            FR    571183.5     174640
#> 13 PGV03.034     BE 616990.0 187209.0            NE    548363.0     206421
#> 14 PGV03.034     GE 499192.0 122622.5            NE    548363.0     206421
#> 15 PGV03.034     NE 548363.0 206421.0            NE    548363.0     206421
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>